# Science fiction movie in which a family (in their car) are abducted by tractor beam

Tags: story-identification, movie, spaceship, robots, alien-abduction

Since my early teens I've had this memories of a few scenes from what looked like a low-budget 80's movie or TV show.

It starts with a family(parents and two teenage children) driving down a packed highway. Their car starts to float up, apparently caught by a tractor beam. They are engulfed by a gigantic spaceship. They are then separated and some of them gets almost eaten by an alien or something. They are then introduced to a queen- a female humanoid with very stylish clothes.

Beyond that I remember only fragments- for example, I remember a small shuttle dropping one of the humans on a very green planet...where he is supposed to deactivate a robot or something.

For the past 10 years I have been obsessed with these images, I don't know if it  was a real movie or just something I dreamt up as a child reading sci-fi comics.

Comment: If there's anything else you can remember, particularly from [this list](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info), don't hesitate to [edit] it into your question.

Answer (score 4):

If you are fuzzy on some of the details, you MIGHT be thinking of [Mom and Dad Save the World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mom_and_Dad_Save_the_World).  Near the beginning, they dragged off into space, and eventually to another planet, via some kind of tractor beam, while in their station wagon.

Comment: Definitely NOT this. They get pulled to a new planet entirely.

Comment: @KingofNES ...but, in this film they do get pulled to a new planet. Did you read the description linked?

Comment: Thank you guys for all your effort!! :)) I distinctly remember that there were at least 4 people , a parents and their two children I think! I don't thing this was the movie!

Comment: I've seen the movie-was bleh lol